# Is there another way to save the Graph of preservation loss and learning rate

Tags: pytorch, fast-ai

I use fastai's learn class to train on a remote cloud server.
Generally, we will adjust the learning rate based on the relationship between the learning rate and the loss.

```
learn.lr_find()

learn.recorder.plot()
```

However, for some reason, the remote server cannot return this relationship graph.

**Are there other ways we can Save the relationship between them and draw locally?**

Answer (score 1):

OK,I found the answer.

```
graph=learn.recorder.plot(return_fig=True)
graph.savefig('loss.png')
```

And it will return a image named loss.png.

and i can view the relationship between loss and learning rate through this image